# URL not available from postman, but appears to be running in cli

Tags: java, postman, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an instance of a `hybris` server running on my local machine on port `9002` (debug). If I run `lsof -i :9002` I get:

```
COMMAND  PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    7154 myusername   52u  IPv6 0xdaced8616ebceeff      0t0  TCP *:dynamid (LISTEN)
```

However, if I send a request from Postman it says the URL is not available:

[image: Postman error message]

The URL is not available from the browser either. If this is a problem with my code, why does the server appear as listening?

Comment: I can't, too big

Comment: Does using `curl` work? I had a similar situation and turning off SSL settings on Postman helped.

Comment: Are you able to access `/hac` form your browser? Are you trying to run out of box setup? or you have changed any configuration.. like ports, webroots, etc? Add more information to your question like URL you are trying to access, properties, server log, error on the browser screen, etc.

Comment: Check your console during build and server startup for any errors. Usually this happens when there is a runtime error connected to the spring.